# Find element in an array (matlab) with defined position (of time array)

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, time, position

I have one array that depends on another (i.e. I have the array of the tension (V) in function of the array of the time). I'd like to find the position of an element of the array of the tension at a particular moment of time (i.e. corresponding to a particular position of the time vector). How can I do that?

I have tried the following:

```
VMpzt = max(V); 
%find the maximum value of the array of tensions 
idxV = find(V == VMpzt); 
%find the corresponding index 
idxt = t(idxV);
%find the corresponding index of time vector 
diff = 0.0048377328; 
idxt2 = idxt-diff; 
%in fact, I am interested at the index of time that corresponds to this particular position 
Vmpzt = V(idxt2); %find the corresponding position of V array
```

doing so, I get the error

> "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values."

Comment: Can you show us the vectors and the solutions you tried ?

Comment: I have tried the following:

`VMpzt = max(V); %find the maximum value of the array of tensions  
    idxV = find(V == VMpzt); %find the correspoding index  
    idxt = t(idxV); %find the corresponding index of time vecotr  
    diff = 0.0048377328;  
    idxt2 = idxt-diff;  %in fact, I am interested at the index of time that corresponds to this particular position  
    Vmpzt = V(idxt2);  %find the corresponding position of V array`  

doing so, I get the error "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values."

Answer (score 0):

```
idxt = t(idxV); %find the corresponding index of time vector
```

This line does not do what your comment suggests. It find the time at that index, not the index. You then subtract `diff` from it and try use it as an index but it isn't an index, it's a time. I think your variable names confused you. Try this:

```
[V_max, V_max_index] = max(V);
t_at_v_max = t(V_max_index); %find the TIME where V was max
diff = 0.0048377328; 
t_desired = t_at_v_max - diff;
```

You now want the index where `t` equals `t_desired`. Because you are dealing with [floating point numbers](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) you can't just do `find(t==t_desired)` so instead we need to do this:

```
t_desired_index = find(abs(t-t_desired) < diff/1000); %1000 chosen arbitrarily, you might need to change it
```

and finally:

```
Vmpzt = V(t_desired_index );
```